# Is Superset Time Range Dynamic?

Tags: apache-superset

I'm creating a chart and I can therefore use the 'advanced' time range option. Since I only want to see data from the start of the year to now. Therefore:

If now = 2022-12-01 then I expect that when I load the chart the "now" will always be the current date.

I cant see anything in the documentation that discusses this chart filter in depth. Is it static or dynamic does anyone know?

Example Image of setting the time range on a chart

[image: 1]

It seems to capture now as today, however the "Actual time range" looks to be a hardcoded range. Its not clear what happens once I save the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem when i started out with superset.
From what i found out at the moment there is no fancy way to achieve this with the GUI alone. By default the time range is dynamic.
To get data for a specific time range we did a query in the Advanced tab

[Screenshot of advanced time range config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8vfe.png)

In the START field use `datetrunc(datetime('now'), year)`
In the END field use `datetime('now')`

To vary the time range you can swap out **year** in the start field with day, month, week or an absolute date.